# How can I download Xbox-live SDK package for Android?

Tags: android, xbox-live

I'm researching to integrate the Xbox-live to my Android project. I found this document: [Get started with the Xbox Live APIs on Android - Xbox Live | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/gaming/xbox-live/get-started/setup-ide/managed-partners/as-android/other/android-get-started-with-xsapi)

But currently I'm stuck at this step:

> Download the SDK package and extract the Android SDK binaries to a local folder (for example, C:\XboxLiveSDK)

I find an URL on github https://github.com/microsoft/xbox-live-api but it doesn't contain Android package.

Does anyone know where to download the package?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you in a managed partner program with MS the like of ID@Xbox? Due to how the documentation is structured and titled being a managed partner is a pre-requisite to get access to the libraries you refer to.

[image]

If you go up in the documentation tree you will find this page of information about [partner programs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/gaming/xbox-live/get-started/setup-partner-center/setup-partner-center_nav)

If you are in the Creators Program you currently only can develop against Windows 10.